# Why are most posix named objects designed with unlink?

Tags: operating-system, resources, posix, glibc

Most POSIX named objects (or all?) have unlink functions. e.g:
[`shm_unlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_unlink)
[`mq_unlink`](http://%20https://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_unlink)

They all have in common, that they remove the name of the object from the system, causing next opens to fail or create a new object.

Why is this designed like this? I know, this is connected to the "everything is a file" policy, but why not delete the file on close? Would you do this the same if you create a new interface?

I think, this has a big drawback. Say, we have a server process and several client processes. If any process unlinks the object (by mistake) all new clients would not find the server. (This can be prohibited by user permissions on the according file, but still...)

Would it not be better, if it had reference counting and the name would be removed automatically when the last object is closed? Why would you want to keep it open?

Comment: The rationale (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html) suggests they should be implementable with `open` and `mmap`, but other parts of POSIX don't have a notion of "files that auto-unlink when nobody has them open", so perhaps ease of implementation is the reason.

Comment: Just for clarification, most file objects do have reference counting, and open files remain accessible to programs that have a file descriptor to it, even after other processes unlink them. There is a semantic difference between having no process *currently* using an object (closed) vs no process ever needing to use an object in the future (unlinked).

Answer (score 1):

Because they are low level tools that could be used when performance matters. Deleting the object when it is not used to create it again on next use has a (slight) performance penalty against keeping it alive.

I once used a named semaphore that I used to synchronize accesses to a spool with various producers and consumers. I used an init module to create the named semaphore that was called as part of the boot process, and all other processes knew that the well known semaphore should exist.

If you want a more programmer friendly way that creates the object on demand and destroys it when it is no longer used, you can build a higher level library and encapsulate the creation/unlink operations in it. But if the system call included it, it would not be possible to build a user level library avoiding it.

Comment: I'm sure that it was not due to the performance impact of killing an unused object, rather than giving users the explicit option of handling the object. In general, no processes using an object does not mean that no object *will* use the object in the future. The way I see it, the `open`/`close` interface allows a process to interact with an object, while the `create`/`unlink` interface allows objects to be created, and removed when the programmer deems it will not be needed any more.

Comment: I doubt this is the reason.

Comment: *you can build a higher level library and encapsulate the creation/unlink operations in it*  That creates the problem of how to handle crashes that leave the resource in place. "Hey, this isn't supposed to actually exist yet?!?!"

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I never pretended that writing such a library would be easy, because there are a number of corner cases and it will require a good deal of error processing code. But it is at least *possible*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You know that, I know that.  But someone else contemplating such a design likely hasn't thought through all the implications...

Answer (score 1):

> Would it not be better, if it had reference counting and the name would be removed automatically when the last object is closed?

No.

Because `unlink()` can fail and because always unlinking a resource that can be shared between processes when all processes merely close that resource simply doesn't fit the paradigm of a *shared* resource.

You don't demolish a roller coaster just because there's no one waiting in line to ride it again *at that moment in time*.

Comment: I am sure OP was asking about why POSIX doesn't use Windows semantics for shared objects when object is deleted as soon as the last handle is closed. And it make _a lot of sense_ to do so. POSIX is just horribly misdesigned here and repeats errors of SysV IPC objects.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I question whether the Windows semantics are in fact superior.  A shared semaphore, for example, getting posted by some producer would be deleted should the consumer not be running at that moment in time if the producer were to exit when it's job is done.  The deletion of a *shared* resource needs to be an *explicit* decision.

Comment: You are describing a use case when a process is interacting with another process that might not have started yet. If there is a use case for that, it would probably work better with a non-volatile memory, because such information probably should outlive system shutdown. One point of using processes is to allow system to handle crashes which implies automatic resource cleanup, instead we got another interface which generates unused objects and requires manual intervention to clean them.

Comment: @StaceyGirl "Better" is entirely subjective - I prefer roller coasters that don't get demolished if the line just happens to be empty.  The Windows "delete when not used" paradigm objectively precludes entire families of solutions.

Comment: I have seen many-many cases when Windows semantics was needed, but I have never met one that was fine with POSIX (lack of) solution. I have also seen too much commonly used software leaving unused garbage objects in my system.

Comment: @StaceyGirl There's no case where Windows semantics are "needed".  It's not hard to handle crashes leaving shared resources in an inconsistent state.  If you can't do that you're in over your head coding in C even on Windows - or **any** OS or environment. Calling explicit deletion of shared resources a "lack of solution" smacks of a need for hand-holding.  Files are shared resources too, that are not useful unless they're actually open by a process...

Comment: Resource cannot be explicitly removed when your process gets killed/crashes. Today we can use systemd to auto-clean some things (certainly says something about "lack of solution"), but not every system uses systemd and not every process can/want to be a systemd service.

Comment: @StaceyGirl No OS can implicitly remove any shared resource on persistent storage if the power gets pulled, so that can't be a generic solution anyway.  Nor can any OS know what "consistent" means for the state of shared resources in your process, yet now your invoking `systemd` as another hand-holding tool?  If **you** can not take a post-crash inconsistent set of shared resources for your process and recover, **you** are not able to create robust, reliable processes on **any** operating system because there is **no** operating system that can guarantee consistency after a crash.

Comment: Most IPC does not need persistent storage, but still does not want to leave any garbage if, lets say, process tree is killed (because data becomes useless). This cannot be handled without help from a supervisor (kernel or pid 1). With Windows kernel does this, on Linux you might use `systemd` to ensure this. If you are not on Windows or have no `systemd`, then you are out of lack and probably want to reboot your system periodically.

Comment: @StaceyGirl You are regurgitating [cargo-cult aphorisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and displaying no understanding at all that the only thing that can guarantee **your** process resources are in a consistent state is **you**, because your statement "This cannot be handled without help from a supervisor" is **completely false**. Writing code that implements, "Hey, this semaphore isn't supposed to even exist yet at this point in my startup, so that means I'm doing crash cleanup" is demonstrably **not** impossible. And you have to do that on all OSes anyway.

Comment: You are making an assumption that resource name is always the same and doesn't change, even though it can be generated or specified from outside which mean your process _will_ leave garbage after it is killed and you won't be able to unlink it because you won't have a name to check for. Funny that your resorted to "cargo-cult" blaming. POSIX people like to lash out on Windows, but with all its downsides, some parts of it are much better designed than Unix ever was.

Comment: @StaceyGirl **Your** process provides the name for a POSIX shared resource.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html for an example.  Are you claiming you don't know what your process did in the naming of its shared resources?  **You** have already lost control of your resources in that case.  This appears relevant to your claims now:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_holes

Comment: @StaceyGirl Riiiight. You've already demonstrated you think a process that doesn't know what name it used for it's shared resources is somehow acceptable. Your entire position boils down to "Unix doesn't hold my hand (and I need help)!!! Therefore Windows is better!"  Guess what?  There are entire groups of programmers who don't need that hand-holding help because one, that hand-holding is not sufficient to produce truly reliable systems anyway and two, that hand-holding precludes entire solutions. Not only that, you confuse bad implementations with bad paradigms.

Comment: (cont) If the Windows "design" is so great, why do even non-programmers know what BSOD means?  And why does it even have [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death)?  And is [mocked worldwide in cartoons for the entire planet](https://www.google.com/search?q=BSOD+in+cartoon&tbm=isch)

Comment: 1. Never said that Windows was great, I said some parts are better designed and some a more flawed (btw I only use Linux) 2. BSOD exists because of Kernel Panic (also has a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic)) 3. You cannot do proper resource cleanup on a Unix system on many layers and the fact that most used programs leak resources on Unix but don't on Windows proves this. And no, its not because some implementations are flawed, you just can't do better.

Comment: You've already demonstrated that you're unaware of how to create automatically-cleaned up shared resources on POSIX systems. Do you want me to explain that to you?  (Hint:  one way involves `mmap()`'ing a file then unlinking that file...)  POSIX gives you the tools to do what you need to do without holding your hand in ways that preclude solutions.  You're ignorance of those methods is not a problem with POSIX.

Comment: Funny how you come up with _the wrong way_ of doing this, letting your program leak that file if it dies before unlinking. "Works most of the time" mentality plagues Unixes. I just ran-killed a Qt app (qtcreator) in a loop. Now I have to clean a mess of temporary files, sockets and SysV garbage...easier to just reboot. I wish it could just use Windows primitives. Not only NT kernel can delete-on-close files, you can open-something-delete atomically there too (although this requires calling Nt API directly - what a shame it is not exposed to WinAPI).

Comment: @StaceyGirl *Funny how you come up with the wrong way of doing this* The close-minded utter arrogance of that statement is telling.  *etting your program leak that file if it dies before unlinking*  Then put your shared resource in a memory-backed filesystem that's automatically cleaned up when the system crashes.  That was available on [SunOS back in 1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).  Long before Windows even dreamed of [uptimes greater than 49.7 days.](https://www.cnet.com/news/windows-may-crash-after-49-7-days/) *

Comment: Not the system crash, the _process_ crash or termination. Creating anything in a memory-backed filesystem doesn't change anything. And with cleaning files you can at least enumerate them. Enumerating `shm_open` objects is not in POSIX and if you writing system-specific code, then there is no point in using this POSIX crap. Your attempts to push everything on a programmer are meaningless - there is nothing programmer can do to stop his process from being killed by `SIGKILL`, only system-wide supervisor can handle this.

Comment: _The last problems you're stating were solved in POSIX systems 33 years ago._ What problem? If you are talking about file unlinking, then Unix doesn't even allow you to remove file using fd - you can mess with `/proc/self` all you want, but your code will be racy, while NT always had handles tied to a file name and could atomically open-remove file.